# Silent mode setup for jre(Java) throwing error when choosing the INSTALLDIR

Tags: java, powershell, silent-installer

Installing jre in silent mode, throwing the followinng error

```
PS E:\java> start-process jre-8u201-windows-x64.exe /s /v"/qn INSTALLDIR= E:\MYInstallation" -PassThru -Wait


Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '/v/qn INSTALLDIR= E:\MYInstallation'
At line:1 char:1
+ start-process jre-8u201-windows-x64.exe /s /v"/qn INSTALLDIR= E:\MYI ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Comment: You could give something like `Start-Process jre-8u201-windows-x64.exe -ArgumentList '/s', '/v', '/qn', 'INSTALLDIR=E:\MYInstallation' -PassThru -Wait` a shot.

Comment: Any other suggesstions??

Comment: Probably a crud load of suggestions but frankly... not a single one until you explain how this didn't work. I'm not spending my evening guessing stuff.

Comment: Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
     38       4      744      32988       0.09   3724   2 jre-8u201-windows-x64


PS E:\java>

Comment: when I use the @notjustme command its gives me the above output and exits without installing anything

Comment: with exitcode -80